# "brew install python3" fails to compile pyexpat

Tags: high-sierra, xcode, homebrew, python

`brew install python3` fails with a pyexpat error, which means the installed Python can't parse XML (breaking `pip` etc). Here's the relevant excerpt from `~/Library/Logs/Homebrew/python/02.make`:

```
*** WARNING: renaming "pyexpat" since importing it failed: dlopen(build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.7/pyexpat.cpython-37m-darwin.so, 2): Symbol not found: _XML_ErrorString
  Referenced from: build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.7/pyexpat.cpython-37m-darwin.so
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.7/pyexpat.cpython-37m-darwin.so
```

`nm -gU /usr/lib/libexpat.1.dylib` shows that this symbol is defined there, but according to `otool -L` the pyexpat `.so` file doesn't mention it; its only dependency is:

```
/usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1252.50.4)
```

Again from `02.make`, this is how the pyexpat `.so` was built (I've added line breaks to make it more readable):

```
clang \
-bundle \
-undefined dynamic_lookup \
-isysroot \
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.13.sdk \
build/temp.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.7/private/tmp/python-20180929-40812-11ki5rr/Python-3.7.0/Modules/pyexpat.o \
build/temp.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.7/private/tmp/python-20180929-40812-11ki5rr/Python-3.7.0/Modules/expat/xmlparse.o \
build/temp.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.7/private/tmp/python-20180929-40812-11ki5rr/Python-3.7.0/Modules/expat/xmlrole.o \
build/temp.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.7/private/tmp/python-20180929-40812-11ki5rr/Python-3.7.0/Modules/expat/xmltok.o \
-L/usr/local/lib \
-o build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.7/pyexpat.cpython-37m-darwin.so
```

I'm running XCode 9.4.1 on mac OS 10.13.6 (17G65). Other reports indicate that the problem might be that my Xcode version is newer than my macOS version, but due to work policy I can't upgrade to Mojave just yet.

Any ideas how I can get a working Python 3 install?

Answer (score 2):

I eventually fixed this by

- uninstalling XCode altogether (and relying on the xcode-select command line tools)
- cherry-picking [this commit](https://github.com/adrw/homebrew-core/commit/223abd59d377c10128f08e65e333d001980e423b) into my homebrew-core Taps directory
- reinstalling python3

Comment: the commit link is not longer valid

Comment: I'm sorry; I didn't know git commit links died :(